# Google Cloud Talent API radius miles configuration Issue

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution, google-cloud-api-keys

I am trying to use google cloud talent API to pull jobs given a title and location but it is not giving me any search results. I have set up the project ID and tenant ID correctly.

Here is the script I am using:

```
from google.cloud import talent_v4beta1

def search_jobs(project_id, tenant_id, job_title="nurse", location="49008", radius_miles=50):
    client = talent_v4beta1.JobServiceClient()

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/tenants/{tenant_id}"
    request_metadata = {"user_id": "user123", "session_id": "session123", "domain": "www.example.com"}
    job_query = {"query": job_title, 
                 "location_filters": [{
                    "address": location,
                    "distance_in_miles": radius_miles
                }]}
    request = {"parent": parent, "request_metadata": request_metadata, "job_query": job_query}

    response = client.search_jobs(request)

    print(response.matching_jobs)

    for result in response.matching_jobs:
        print(f"Job title: {result.job.title}")
        print(f"Job description: {result.job.description}")
        print(f"Job location: {result.job.addresses}")

# Example usage
project_id = "x"  # Replace with your project ID
tenant_id = "x"    # Replace with your tenant ID
search_jobs(project_id, tenant_id)
```

When I run this code I am not getting any search results and it seems to be because the radius_miles is too small for any jobs to be present. I have gone through the documentation and tried to set the radius_miles manually but it does not seem to work still. When I print out the response here is what I get:

```
SearchJobsPager<location_filters {
  location_type: POSTAL_CODE
  postal_address {
    region_code: "US"
    postal_code: "49008"
    administrative_area: "MI"
    locality: "Kalamazoo"
    address_lines: "Kalamazoo, MI 49008, USA"
  }
  lat_lng {
    latitude: 42.2609411
    longitude: -85.612648
  }
  radius_miles: 0.00161218820789593
}
```

My hypothesis is that it is not returning any results due to the small radius_miles parameter but I am not sure how to set this. Any assistance would be amazing!